# Emacs Mac port - double-click title bar to maximize

Tags: osx, frames

When running the GNU Emacs on Mac OS (either from [Emacs for OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com) or from [emacs-app](https://ports.macports.org/port/emacs-app/) on MacPorts) when I double-click the title bar, first the window maximizes vertically.  When I double-click it again, it maximizes horizontally.  By "maximize" I mean it occupies available screen space but still leaves the menu bar visible; this is not the MacOS "full screen" feature.

However when I use the [Mitsuharu Yamamoto Emacs Mac port](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/src/master/) (I use the one from MacPorts, [emacs-mac-app](https://ports.macports.org/port/emacs-mac-app/)) double-clicking the title bar alternates between maximized vertically and not maximized vertically.  It does no horizontal maximizing.

Is there any way to make the Mitsuharu Yamamoto Emacs have the same zooming behavior as the vanilla GNU one?

Answer (score 0):

You asked my question!

I find this answer on [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen).

Both `M-x toggle-frame-fullscreen` or `M-x toggle-frame-maximized (M-<f10>)` are available without having to define a function from below.

It works on my machine.

To make double-click works, we have to find a way to link the double-click event with one of these functions. I don't know how to do it.